# Add name and date to new tab

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new tab, then give the tab a name and the current date. like: Group Bene 8/27/2019

I can get the tab to be named as a date, or as Group Bene, but I cannot get both on the same tab.

```
Sub Refresh()

myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmmm_dd_yyyy")

'add new tab
Sheets.Add.Name = myWorksheetName
```

The above gives me the tab with the dat. I've tried:

myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmmm_dd_yyyy Group Bene")

myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmmm_dd_yyyy" + "Group Bene")

myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmmm_dd_yyyy"&"Group Bene")

I get errors.

Comment: `myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmm_dd_yyyy") & " Group Bene"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple concatenation here, with the `" Group Bene"` (including a space) *outside* the `Format`:

```
myWorksheetName = Format(Now, "mmm_dd_yyyy") & " Group Bene"
```

returns

```
Aug_27_2019 Group Bene
```